# Multiple the second element of the Tuple to Key value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

There is list of tuples as below:

```
list_tuple = [('A',1),('B',2),('C',3)] and 
dict_brand = {'A':25,'B':30,'C':20}
```

I have to calculate the equation where:

`price = A*1 + B*2 + C*3`, where A,B,C values are taken from the dictionary correspondingly.

Comment: what issue are you facing with your code, can you share it

Comment: Please show your attempt. Don't expect free code.

Comment: not sure this has anything to do with pandas.

Comment: `sum([dict_brand[k[0]]*k[1] for k in list_tuple ])`

Comment: I tried to solve the problem by creating another dictionary from the list of the tuples, I was able to solve it but then it's adding another step to the problem. This a part of the problem I was trying to solve. In my problem, I have a data frame, wherein one column I have a list of tuples and I have a dictionary similar to as posted and have to calculate the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
price = sum(dict_brand[x] * y for x, y in list_tuple)
print(price) #145
```